# Unescape with pipe

Tags: bash, sed, pipe

Given this file

```
$ cat foo.txt
\"That's funny, haha\"
```

I can unescape the double quotes with `read`

```
$ read bar < foo.txt

$ echo $bar
"That's funny, haha"
```

However can this be done with a pipe? Something like

```
cat foo.txt | unescape
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to do it

```sh
sed -r 's/\\(.)/\1/g'
```

Comment: On Mac OS X it’s `-E` instead of `-r`

Comment: This will only work for escaped ascii chars like space, backslash etc.  If it's escaping a newline, tab or unicode value it will not work

Answer (score 2):

Yes or no, depending on what you mean by your question.  The pipe cannot remove the backslash, but, as you saw, `read` can:

```
cat foo.txt | read bar
```

This is, though, a useless use of `cat`  AND it won't do what you need anyway.

In Bash, this has the added "feature" that each side of the pipe runs in it's own process.  This means that the variable (`bar`) will not be available in the calling process.  So, the backslashes will be removed but it won't do you a bit of good.

Yes, you *could* contrive to capture it:

```
bar=$(cat foo.txt | { read bat;echo $bat;})
```

But that's not just horrible to look at, it is inefficient as well.

Stick to redirection.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question now, but I'll add this answer so that it's here for the record since I had the same question and couldn't find a solution anywhere. I came up with this solution which works for any string escape sequences:

```
echo "" | gawk "{ print \"\`cat foo.txt\`\" }"

echo "" | gawk "{ print \"$(cat foo.txt)\" }"

echo "" | gawk "{ print \"$(< foo.txt)\" }"
```

They're all variants of the same operation, and note the use of backquotes in the first one. They are utilizing the unescaping done by gawk's print command, and are limited to a one-line input file (although I'm sure that a more complex variant could be worked out for multi-line input).

Note that `cat foo.txt | gawk '{ printf $0 }'`, which I thought might be a solution, doesn't work - it seems that gawk doesn't unescape its input, even when that is used as the printf format string which it would otherwise unescape.